# How do i get a specfic piece of data from a user input list

Tags: python, list

I need the code to find the gradient (slope calculation) using the first to inputs but i cant get the code to find the individual inputs

```
heart_rate = []
max_length = 5
while len(heart_rate) < max_length:
  hr = int(input("enter heartrate after exercise: "))
  heart_rate.append(hr)
#Print data set
print(heart_rate)

#Calculate the gradient of HR recovery for the data entered
n = len(heart_rate)
def HR_gradient(heart_rate,n):
  time = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
  for idx in list(heart_rate):
    gradient = (time[0]-time[1])/(len[0]-len[1])
  return (gradient)
```

I've tried len() but its not working.

Comment: `gradient = (time[0]-time[1])/(len[0]-len[1])` isn't going to work because `len` is a function, not an array

Comment: Your HR_gradient function is confusing: what use is the argument n ? What use is idx ? You'd probably better tell us exactly what you want to calculate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`len` is a function, not a list. To get the first 2 inputs of the list you would have to use `heart_rate[0]` and `heart_rate[1]` respectively. The code should be like this instead:

```
gradient = (time[0]-time[1])/(heart_rate[0]-heart_rate[1])
```

But keep in mind that just changing this wont fix your `HR_gradient` function, since:

1. You're not using the `n` variable at all inside the function even though you have it as an argument.
2. You're iterating over `heart_rate` with `idx`, but you're not using it, so everytime it loops, it will just keep using the first 2 inputs of `time` and `heart_rate`, ignoring the rest.